# Don't pull it. You will hit by your foot

Tags: grammar

He wanted to pull over the bottle on the table.

> "Don't pull it. You will hit by yourself."
>
> "Don't pull it. You will hit by your foot."

How do I say the bottle might fell right to his foot and got hurt.

Comment: Don't pull it. You'll drop it on your foot.

Comment: Equivalent idiom: Don't mess with that, you'll put somebody's eye out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. @The Photon

> Don't pull it. You'll drop it on your foot